# How to check user in custom / index action with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to check a couple of rules in my `photos#latest` view, but I don't know how to define User in my **Photos Controller**.

I want to check:

```
<% if current_user == @photo.user or current_user.has_role? :admin %>
 <%= link_to "Editar Spot", edit_user_photo_path(@user, @photo), class: "edit" %>
<% end %>
```

In my controller:

```
def latest
    @user = current_user
    @categories = Category.all(:order => 'name')
    @zones = Zone.all(:order => 'name')
    @photos = Photo.latest_photos.quality.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    @action = 'general'
    render :index
end
```

That will say:

**undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass**

How should I define User in my controller when I don't have an ID or params?

Thanks

Comment: What's your error backtrace?

Comment: @MarekLipka, in this case backtrace doesn't matter, because code is invalid. @Gibson where is your `@photo` variable defined?

Comment: @Gibson you should place this backtrace in question instead of comment.

Comment: @IS04 you're right. `@photo` is `nil` and that's why this code doesn't work.

Comment: @IS04 I've updated the latest action

Comment: @Gibson backtrace is no longer necessary. But you should paste whole view template code.

Comment: So stupid. Photo wasn't defined. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error `` undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass ``. Your @photo variable seems to be nil. You have to first check if @photo is not nil and then you could check if the photo's user is the current_user. Try for below code or make sure @photo has some value.

```
<% if (@photo.present? and current_user == @photo.user) or current_user.has_role? :admin %>
```